Read from a Word doc and output to Excel
I am trying to open a Word document using the win32com.client, read in the headers from the document and then write them to an Excel file.  I can successfully open the Word file, read in the headers and then print them to the screen.
Here is my code:
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

Excel_File = "header.xslx"

Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
Select the default sheet (usually named 'Sheet')
sheet = (workbook.active)
data = ['Req_Name']


# Create a Word application instance
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

#Open the Word document
document = word.Documents.Open('header.docx')

#Access headers using the Document object
for headings in iter_headings(document.Paragraphs):
your text**print(headings.Range.Text)
Req_Name=(headings.Range.Text)
sheet.append(row)



workbook.save(Excel_File)
workbook.close()

Close the Word document (optional)
document.Close()
word.Quit()

Here is the output to the screen which is all of the headers in this test Word document
Test 1 Header
Test 2 Header
Test 3 Header
Test 4 Header
Test 5 Header
Test 6 Header

I think that I need to write the output data to a variable or list and then write that to Excel.  But I am stumped on the mechanics.

As an alternative, let me point out that Excel is perfectly happy to open a CSV file.  Perhaps you could write your data in CSV format for import.

openpyxl's append function takes an Iterable of data representing a row in a spreadsheet, and adds it to the end (ref)
If you want the headings to each be on their own row, use:
for heading in iter_headings(document.Paragraphs):
    sheet.append([heading.Range.Text])

(It looks like you were trying to do that, but I can't tell what the issue was since you didn't provide an Exception and row is undefined in the code you provided.)
If you want all headings on the same row, it's even easier--just append the entire list:
sheet.append([heading.Range.Text for heading in iter_headings(document.Paragraphs)])

Highly recommend you read through the openpyxl tutorial if you need to do anything else to your spreadsheet.
Alternatively, as Tim mentioned in his comment, you could also consider working with a different format.
To write to CSV:
import csv
with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for heading in iter_headings(document.Paragraphs):
        wr.writerow([heading])


Also, remove the parentheses from the line sheet = (workbook.active). They're not doing anything and make it look like you're trying to construct a tuple.
